# Make case insensitive in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, turtle-rdf, sparql-generate

I am creating a knowledge graph in SPARQL. I am importing data from a csv file.
Now I want to filter a data corresponding to a country.
In the csv I don't want to make data in column to all lower or upper case.

Now I want to filter a data, such that I want a SPARQL query that can get me data which is case insensitive (to give data either when typed lower or upper case).

I used the FILTER statement as below:
FILTER(?country, "Japan").
How to make Japan case insensitive

FILTER(?country, "Japan").

Expecting a filter or any other statement that makes it case insensitive

Answer (score 2):

One way is to convert `?country` to lower case and test against the lower case version as in:

```
  FILTER (lcase(?country) = "japan")
```

Likewise you could test it after converting to upper case

```
  FILTER (ucase(?country) = "JAPAN")
```

Comment: thank you, but I want a single command which could work both for lower or upper case.

Comment: The FILTER I suggested will do that. It first converts the value of `?country` and then tests it. If you just want to make sure the value is some form of Japan (could be japan, Japan, JAPAN, JaPaN etc.) converting to a known form (like lower case) and then testing against that form will work. If I am misunderstanding what you really want to do can you please clarify the question. I was not suggesting you need both filters, you can just pick one of the FILTER I showed.

Comment: `lcase` works fine.

It is also possible to use `REGEX(?country, "^ja..n$", "i")` for more than case-insensitve string matching